# Run-time error 5 invalid procedure call or argument when applying conditional formatting programmatically

Tags: excel, vba

I’m trying to apply different colors to cells in columns B and C if specified conditions are met. I have two AND formulas

1. if B is not blank and the corresponding cell in G is not blank.
2. If C is not blank and the corresponding cell in G is not blank.

I get an invalid procedure error in the function. `r.FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:=formula`

What am I doing wrong?

Please see the code below:

```
    Public Sub applyColor()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, thisWs As Worksheet

    Dim myRangeB As Range
    Dim myRangeC As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set thisWs = ActiveSheet
    setSheets


    With ActiveSheet 'delete conditional formatting
        .Range("B:C").FormatConditions.Delete
        lastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set myRangeB = .Range("B2:B" & lastRow) 'The range to be formatted
        Set myRangeC = .Range("C2:C" & lastRow)

    End With


    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.name = wsColon.name Or ws.name = wsLung.name Or ws.name = wsMela.name Then
            ws.Activate

            Call FormatRange(myRangeB, 3, "=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($B1)),NOT(ISBLANK($G1)))")
            Call FormatRange(myRangeC, 29, "=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($C1)),NOT(ISBLANK($G1)))")

        End If
    Next
    thisWs.Activate

End Sub

Public Sub FormatRange(r As Range, colorIndex As Integer, formula As String)
r.FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:=formula
r.FormatConditions(r.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.colorIndex = colorIndex
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I realize that your local settings require a `;` in the formulas instead of a `,` but in vba one must use `,` instead.  Try replacing the `;` delimiter with `,`.

Comment: The code now executes, thanks to your suggestion; however, the conditional formatting is not working as expected.  It’s highlighting blank cells and I was expecting to see color change once new data is entered into col B and C, but it’s not changing color. I have data validation dropdown in B and C and I’m not sure if it’s affecting conditional formatting. Do you know?

Comment: The main problem that it's not cycling through Colon, Lung and Melanoma sheets.  It applies formatting to the `Activesheet` only.

Comment: That is because you are setting the ranges to the activesheet before the loop.  You need to re select the ranges inside the loop before calling the sub.  Put your `with` block after the `ws.activate`.

Comment: Yes, I got it thank you!